# disable/hide "[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on" for Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook in Ansible and get a lot of warnings

```
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [XXXXXXX]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
```

Since everything is working fine I want to disable these warnings.

My ansible.cfg:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args= -A

[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

What can I do to disable these warnings or to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `no_log: true` in your playbook to disable all outputs from your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the sftp subsystem in your sshd_config file.  I'll bet that you've got a semi-hardened sshd_config and the sftp subsystem is commented out.

On my RHEL8 system:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

The other thing you can do is change the way Ansible transfers files.  Use only one of the below options based on your version of Ansible installed:

```
[ssh_connection]
;scp_if_ssh = true
transfer_method = scp
```